# How to compare two Deming regressions?

Tags: r, regression, deming-regression

I have two small data sets. For each data set, I performed a Deming regression. Hence, I have, for each data set, the relationship between X and Y in the form of slope+intercept coefficients.

Now, I want to know if the relationship between X and Y is the same for the two data sets. Meaning I want to compare the regressions and test whether the slope+intercept coefficients are the same. In R, there's the `strucchange` package allowing to run Chow Tests.

However, I understood when reading the  [strucchange pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/strucchange.pdf) that the Chow Tests works for OLS rather than TLS, implying it does not work for Deming regressions.

Long story short: is there any function that performs the comparison of Deming regressions?

```
# package loading and data definition

library(MethComp)
X1=c(80,170,254,63,153,247)
Y1=c(248,252,168,283,283,142)
X2=c(80,189,292,87,189,280)
Y2=c(212,167,38,252,203,107)

# plot
x11()
plot(c(1,1),c(1,1),type="n", xlab="X value", ylab="Y value",  cex=1, xlim=c(0,300), ylim=c(0,300))
points(X1, Y1, pch=21, bg="blue", col="black", cex=1.5)
points(X2, Y2, pch=21, bg="red", col="black", cex=1.5)

# Deming regressions
for (i in 1:2) {
  X=switch(i,X1,X2)
  Y=switch(i,Y1,Y2)
  color=switch(i,"blue","red")

  dem_reg <- Deming(X,Y,vr=var(Y)/var(X))
  deming_slope=dem_reg[2]
  deming_intercept=dem_reg[1]
  abline(a=deming_intercept,b=deming_slope,lty="longdash", col=color, lwd=2)
}
```

[image: Deming regression for both data sets]

Comment: There's the `boot=TRUE` option to `Deming` which computes fitted parameter uncertainties via bootstrap sampling. For your data the estimates of slope and intercept are within the other models 2.5% - 97.5% interval so probably can't conclude any difference...

Comment: @Spacedman: I was hesitating to do so. However, I'm not sure my question is that complicated. We'll see quickly I guess.

Comment: @Spacedman: regarding your second comment, I agree it is a reasonable method (and thanks, btw, for your time). Any official test to go with?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46295/estimated-critical-value-for-hypothesis-testing

Comment: http://clinchem.aaccjnls.org/content/clinchem/44/5/1024.full.pdf

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen: thanks for your comments. However, I'm not sure the link solves the problem here: 1)question in link1 seems unanswered, 2)paper from link2, however interesting, compares different deming regressions assuming one is the "true" one (hence the formula of bias given in Appendix). I may well have misunderstood something, so please correct me if I'm wrong (and I hope so!).